# shell_exec PHP communicate with bash script

Tags: php, bash, ssh

So I'm creating a php script that generates an openvpn certificate and I want to do it using a bash script, what's the best to communicate with this bash script so I can respond to it's questions.
Here are the images below
[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36812772/797495

Comment: openvpn.sh: line 37: cd: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0: No such file or directory

Comment: The answer states: ***"Make sure you edit, at least, the following variables OPENVPN_RSA_DIR OPENVPN_KEYS KEY_DOWNLOAD_PATH***" - find out where `openvpn/easy-rsa/` is located and change accordingly

Comment: It's there but there's no 2.0 file/folder

Comment: Could you link me to the appropriate openvpn installation that his script requires?

Comment: I'm using RSA 3 not 2 is there any script for RSA 3 ?

Comment: Please edit the vars script to reflect your configuration,
  then source it with "source ./vars".
  Next, to start with a fresh PKI configuration and to delete any
  previous certificates and keys, run "./clean-all".
  Finally, you can run this tool (pkitool) to build certificates/keys.

zip error: Nothing to do! (/var/www/html/vpns/clients.zip)

Comment: Ok I managed to fix it, this provides only key and certificate I want instead a .ovpn file

Comment: I wrote my own bash script for this as of now, took the time and did thanks for everything :)